# IoC (spring.net) with asp.net - ctor injected non-singleton objects on controller - where do I dispose?

Tags: inversion-of-control, asp.net-mvc-4, spring.net

I'm using asp.net MVC 4 - I have spring.net setup to ctor inject objects on construction of my controllers, but some of the objects aren't singletons, so I'm unsure as to how to handle the dispose method on these objects once the controller is disposed. It just feels wrong calling these objects dispose methods in the controller class as the controller class didn't construct these objects, my IoC container did.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Any decent IoC container should dispose the objects for you. I don't know about spring.net, but have you tested to make sure they are/are not being disposed?

Comment: I don't agree with Dismissile on this. In most cases services should not be disposable, and you should lean on the garbage collector. A decent IoC container however, contains a feature that allows you to configure certain services to be disposed when their scope ends. This should be opt-in, rather than opt-out. I don't know however, how to do this with Spring.Net. Besides, the only container that by default tracks and disposes all instances is Castle Windsor. You can't say that all other containers are not decent.

Comment: Transient (prototype) objects are not tracked by the Spring.NET container, and therefore it will not call `Dispose` on those, even not when the `ApplicationContext` is disposed.

Comment: @steven Windsor is not the only container that does that, Autofac is another example. I'm pretty sure Ninject too. CraigM I would consider another container if I were you. Spring hardly is state of the art in .NET

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments, it's much appreciated - thanks for the knowledge share.

Comment: @kko: AFAIK Autofac doesnt' track all instances by default. It only tracks instances when created inside the context of a lifetime scope.

Comment: @Steven **No** container to my knowledge tracks *all* instances.

Comment: @kko: With Windsor, you **need** to explicitly `Release` everything to `Resolve` explicitly, which mean it tracks *all* instances. btw. I agree with you on the state of Spring.NET. It is completely out of date.

Comment: @Steven it's not true, that part about Windsor. Those two blogposts explain how Windsor operates: http://kozmic.pl/2010/08/19/must-windsor-track-my-components/ http://kozmic.pl/2010/08/27/must-i-release-everything-when-using-windsor/

Comment: @kko: A very interesting read. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider defining `Request` scope for the instances that you want to be disposed at the end of a web request.
See [web object scopes](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/web.html#web-objectscope) in the spring docs for details.

Comment: it works great. Just one thing to note for others that may experience the same problem - when initially adding the " scope='request'" bit, I didn't remove the "singleton='false'" piece and it didn't work - once I removed the singleton piece all together while leaving the scope='request'" piece, it worked. Thanks again.