# Spring.NET IOC / MVC - Disposed database context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, spring.net

I'm using Spring.NET's IOC container in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application. Each controller is getting the EF datacontext from the container:

```
    private readonly IDBContext db =
        (IDBContext) ApplicationHelper.ApplicationContext.GetObject("DatabaseContext");
```

I've scaffolded the controllers, and by default they implement the IDisposable interface, in which the DB connection is disposed - like this:

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        this.db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

That's fine - I would like to keep it like that. However, the 2nd controller that is called, gives an exception, stating that the database context is disposed.

So - what I would like to do is have the IOC container check if the object has been disposed, when the next controller calls the `GetObject()` method. Is that possible, or should I change my design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, object configured in your spring.net web application container have ["application" scope](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/web.html#web-objectscope). This means that your instance named `DatabaseContext` is created once - on web application start-up. The first controller that uses this instance, disposes it, and thereafter it cannot be used by any other controller.

Generally, when using an IOC container, it is bad practice to manage object lifetime yourself like you're doing here in your controllers with the dispose implementation. When possible, you should let your container manage object lifetimes.

In this particular case, it might make sense to create your `DatabaseContext` using `request` scope. When doing so, the spring container will dispose your `DatabaseContext` at the end of your request. You can remove the `this.db.Dispose();`  from `Controller.Dispose` when doing this.

The question [IoC (spring.net) with asp.net - ctor injected non-singleton objects on controller - where do I dispose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834339/ioc-spring-net-with-asp-net-ctor-injected-non-singleton-objects-on-controlle) came along recently; it might be of interest to you too.

Comment: Sweet - spot on answer. Thanks! I've added  scope="request" and will remove all scaffolded dispose code, and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in your IoC container set up method, you configured `IDBContext` as a singleton.

Change it to the instance-based `IDBContext`.